# How can i send JavaPNSpayloads using PushMagic token

Tags: ios, mdm

Hi i am implementing IOS MDM using JavaPNS. Steps performed up to now.

1)I installed xxx.mobileconfig file on IOS Device.
2)I am using JavaPNS for sending notifications.
3)I got PushMagic token from my IOS Device.I got 200 Response.
4)I am using https:// for checkin url. I am using IPCU for generating mobileconfig files.
5)My intension is install some custom payload like disable the camera,disable the youtube ..etc.
6)I am using Restriction payload for that .I am sending the push notification but the IOS Device cannot responding to my server...
The following issue seems to be my issue so can any one guide me.
http://code.google.com/p/javapns/issues/detail?id=103

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

1. Download and install [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1466).
2. Connect your device and open console tab
3. Send a command from server to the device and see logs (see image below)
4. If you can see traces of MDM in the logs such as starting, polling etc, that means the device has received the APNS message and is trying to connect to the MDM server for commands.
5. If in the console you find some error, you need to further investigate.
6. If you don't see any traces of MDM in the logs, then probably there's some issue - either with the server (invalid push token etc) or with the device's internet connection.

Please post the results and ask for more details if required.

[image]

Comment: I have also the same problem I am using APNSWrapper to send the mdm payload but I am not able to see any polling response. APNSWrapper is not giving any error. Please help...

Comment: @Atul: seems point 6 is your problem. Check if the certificate is valid.